# is it even possible to add a 0 in java with terny operators?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Hi I've tried everything from terny operators, if else statements and parsing the int to a string, I am making a clock that reads 4:01 4:02 but instead it outputs 4:1

this is my java code, is it possible to add a 0? or I am going to need something else?

```
package bank;

import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author will
 */
public class dClock {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();

        int min = 1;//time.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int hour =  time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int blank = Integer.parseInt("0");

        int hourOfDay = ((hour > 12) ? (hour - 12) : hour);
        int zero = ((min > 10 ) ? min : blank+min);        
        System.out.println("The time is " + hourOfDay + ":" + zero );


    }

}
```

Comment: Try replacing `int blank = Integer.parseInt("0");` with `String blank = "0";` and `min > 10` with `min >= 10`

Comment: This is the difference between the character "0" and the number 0

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Java Tutorial: Formatting Numeric Print Output](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

For example:

```
  long n = 461012;
  System.out.format("%08d%n", n);    //  -->  "00461012"
```

Another example:

```
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  System.out.format("%tl:%tM %tp%n", c, c, c);  // -->  "2:34 am"
```

Comment: ya, so how would I add system.out in a terny operator, I just cant put a system.out in there

Comment: @user3255751 that is because System.out.println() has no return value ("void"). Use if/else if you want to call System.out.println based on pre-conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `String.format(pattern,data)` with pattern `%02d`

- `%` represents start of pattern
- `2` means that input should be written as at least two characters `__`
- `0` but if input is shorter than two characters fill rest with `0` `_a` -> `0a`
- `d` is short from digit

which all means that digit passed digit should be written using two characters and in case there would be empty space (number is too short like `0`, `1`, `2` till `9`) fill space before it with `0`.

More at [Formatter documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

---

Demo:

```
String formatted = String.format("%02d:%02d", 4,2);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Output: `04:02`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
int blank = Integer.parseInt("0");
```

Since your blank is an integer 0, `blank + min` will be the same as min. Try just using "0" without changing the type.

Also, as David Wallace mentions, you should replace `(min > 10 )` with `(min >= 10 )` or `(min > 9 )`